# SQLite database isolation level on the same connection

Tags: sqlite, isolation-level, sqlite-3.33

SQLite documentation https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html states that on the same connection: "there is no isolation between operations that occur within the same database connection."
As in the client apps SQLite is more often used via single connection, does it mean that isolation level is actually not Serializable, but Read Uncommitted?

Aren't points 1 and 3 in docs contradictory?

1. Transactions in SQLite are SERIALIZABLE. ... 3. A query sees all changes that are completed on the same database connection prior to the start of the query, regardless of whether or not those changes have been committed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No contradiction, because:

> 1. Transactions in SQLite are SERIALIZABLE.

means that no transaction can read uncommited data from *other* transactions and multiple transactions on the same connection are written one after the other.

> 3. A query sees all changes that are **completed** on the same database connection prior to the start of the query, regardless of whether or
>    not those changes have been committed.

However, on a single connection you can open a transaction and have a sequence like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO sample_table (a) VALUES ('test');
SELECT * FROM sample_table;
...
ROLLBACK;
```

The SELECT will return the row 'test', even if the transaction is not yet committed (and even if it will be later rolled back).
This is guaranteed and is normally a desired behavior.

If the two statements are instead executed in parallel (and thus not completed), than the result of the SELECT is undefined and could return or not the 'test' row depending on many internal factors not under your control.